# Metric Screw Size Specification Question: M4x10K?

Tags: screws, fastener

I have a quick question about interpreting a screw specification on a repair diagram. I am usually pretty good with buying replacement screws and threads/sizing but this screw is a metric size (which I am less familiar with) and is written in a way that makes me stumped.

The part description, exactly as it appears on the schematic, is: 'Screw M 4x10K'. Now, M4 is the nominal outer diameter of the head (in mm). Usually, the part following the 'x' is a length (in mm) but the 'K' part is confusing me. Is the 'K' an additional specification or class of screws or is '10K' some length-related specification itself? The screw goes through a plastic part and into a metal part on a vacuum. The manufacturer is based in the UK so I am having some difficulty sorting out what this could be.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Sebo?

The M4 diameter relates to the diameter of the thread not the head though. A M4 thread will typically have a 7mm wide head.

Googling "Sebo M 4 x 10K" seems to find a few references to that screw size.

Comment: 7mm or 8mm, commonly.